# Qur'anic Studies: Meaning of the word "tooth"

Tags: phonology, linguistics, religion, philology

In the meantime, Luxenberg has made two proposals that relate to the question of how the text was first written. First, he argues that the “Ur-Qur’an” sometimes used a single “**tooth**” as mater lectionis not (or not only) for long i, as it does today, but to indicate long a, rather than the alif that later was introduced to mark it; but knowledge of this early convention was subsequently lost, so that the “**tooth**” was then mistakenly pointed to represent y, t, or another letter that the “**tooth**” could represent.

Comment: What does the word "tooth" refer to?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting question but it doesn't seem to be about English. It seems to be about Arabic orthography. On the SE network the most appropriate site for this would be [Linguistics.SE]. Maybe there's an Arabic subreddit?

Comment: I am voting to close because this question has nothing to do with the English language as set out in the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arabic script contains many markings and letter variations. The *tooth* is a basic feature of the script. Its form varies, which partly explains why the quotation deals with it in such detail.

[Creative Arabic Calligraphy](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-arabic-calligraphy-anatomy-of-the-letterforms--cms-22320) "The most basic shape is a vertical stroke (in essence, not necessarily in form), a tooth that can be thought of as the Alif shortened" {Note that Alif is a very common letter consisting of an almost upright stroke}.

Comment: So, to summarize, the meaning of the word "tooth" in OP's context is something that doesn't actually exist in English? Same as [matres lectionis](https://biblicalhebrew.org/mater-lectionis.aspx), which I had to look up.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Because of the flowingly beautiful complexity of Arabic script and the relative simplicity of Roman lettering, I believe it does not exist in English. But I am not qualified to be sure about either teeth or the (novel to me too) matres lectionis.